# how to cross compile for old embedded hardware?

Tags: compilation, arm, cross-compiling, embedded-linux

I would like to ask a question with perhaps a simple solution. I have been playing with this problem for some time, but so far without success. How can I compile an open source application for this hardware?

```
System version: 2.7.28

Emcommd version:    3.81pre3-rc1

Uname -a:   Linux device 3.2.2-em1 #26 Fri Mar 14 08:54:27 CET 2014 armv5tel unknown

CPU Info:   Processor : XScale-PXA270 rev 8 (v5l) BogoMIPS : 518.55 Features : swp half thumb fastmult edsp CPU implementer : 0x69 CPU architecture: 5TE CPU variant : 0x0 CPU part : 0x411 CPU revision : 8 Hardware : EMTEST PXA2xx Platform Revision : 0000 Serial : 0000000000000000

Version:    Linux version 3.2.2-em1 (podolak@podolak-desktop) (gcc version 4.2.1) #26 Fri Mar 14 08:54:27 CET 2014

Uses uClibc
```

It is an older device from the bus for ticketing. EM 126i Mijola
[EM 126i Mijola](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Js5QL.jpg)

For example, I would like to compile some vnc viewer app. Something like this [TigerVNC](https://github.com/TigerVNC/tigervnc). Or at least get JRE up and running. I tried these [embedded JRE packages](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javaseembedded8u211-downloads.html) for ARMv5, but no binary files could run.

I have tried to use tools like crosstool-ng, but I couldn't create a toolchain for this specific hardware.
Can someone guide me in the right direction, or give brief advice on how you would solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: xscales are usuall big endian but this looks to be little.  you can build armv5t binaries with current versions of gcc.

Comment: now building for such an old set of libraries that is another story. likewise porting something newer.  You are better off just getting a pi-zero. or using it bare metal.

Comment: Do you still have this device? If yes, I'm interested to buy it from you.

Answer (score 0):

Most easiest way is to build same versions of GCC and uClibc via Buildroot, and then use this toolchain to build other software, or best, build software you want to use on it directly via buildroot and then copy it into target device.